# In knockout I want to update a table based on the selections in a multiple select drop down list

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and i am trying to update a table with values from a json string based on the users selection. I created a fiddler example of what I am trying to do... I have an array of data

```
[{ Id: 5, Name: 'Administrator', Context:'Website' }, { Id: 7, Name: 'Moderator',Context:'Blog' }, { Id: 10, Name: 'Guest', Context:'Network' }, { Id: 12, Name: 'contributor', Context:'Social' }]
```

So I want to have a multiple select drop down, that when selected or when data is passed into it, the drop down is selected and the table is populated with the values in the drop down plus the context value.

Eventually is will be posted back to the server were I will store the Id's of all the selected values.

Here is the fiddler example.  Thanks for the help.

http://jsfiddle.net/2pjya/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is only partially done, and you would have a lot of options here. I have modified your fiddle a little to show one possible implementation for the problem. Apparently you were making some sort of confusion between the "with" and the "foreach" rendering the table. With that settled, the data is ready to be send to the server.

Hopefully i understood your goal.

Heres the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2pjya/12/

The main conceptual change was the `with: allRoles` replaced by `foreach: Roles`.

Regards